# Can a Conditional CDF Exceed unity?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function

A fundamental question here. We know that:

$F_{X|Y} = \frac{F_{XY}}{F_Y}$

Both $F_{XY}$ and $F_Y$ are bounded between 0 and 1. I guess my question is, is it theoretically possible for the joint cumulative frequency of variables $X$ and $Y$ to be greater than the cumulative frequency of $Y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F_{X|Y}$ is itself a distribution function that returns a probability. For this reason it must be bounded above by 1. Nonetheless, here's a short proof of my claim.

Proof:

Let $A$ be the event that $X \leq a_1, Y \leq a_2$

Let $B$ be the event that $Y \leq a_2$

Clearly the set of outcomes $A$ is contained within $B$ since if $A$ is true, then $B$ must be true.

It is a standard result that if $A \subseteq B$ then $P(A) \leq P(B)$.

Hence,

$F_{XY} (a_1,a_2) = P(X \leq a_1, Y \leq a_2) = P(A) \leq P(B) = P(Y \leq a_2) = F_{Y}(a_2)$

Since this is true for any $a_1, a_2$ it follows that $F_{XY}(x,y) \leq F_Y(y)$

Hence, $F_{X|Y} = \frac{F_{XY}}{F_Y} \leq 1$